# Which partial sum estimates $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}*n!}{n^{n}}$ with an error of at most four hundredths (.04)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I think I have to somehow use this formula for truncating error:

Let $\bigg(a_{n} \bigg)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a decreasing sequence of positive numbers with $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n} = 0$.
Then the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{(n+1)}*a_{n}$ converges. Furthermore, the $jth$ truncation error satisfies the inequality

$E_{j} < a_{j + 1}$

The same results hold for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}*a_{n}$

I don’t understand any of this

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A proof of the alternating series criterion which you use can e.g. be found at the bottom of [this page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx)

Comment: Thank you!
Would it be possible to see how you would solve this? I looked at the page but it looks rather foreign to me. I don't understand the notation. I understand by seeing worked examples.